# Can't connect to L2TP VPN on Windows 10

Tags: networking, vpn

I'm trying to connect to a VPN but takes a lot of time to connect then it fails. But, I can connect to it from my Android Phone and my Ubuntu laptop, and the servers are alright, it's my PC.

The error looks like this:

[image]

What should I do to fix it? Probably installing a VPN client, but I don't know which one is good. I want to mention that one month ago the VPN connection was alright.

Comment: What's your system version? I have Windows 10 1703 version, after installing new update, it couldn't connect VPN server with build-in VPN. This could be a potential bug

Comment: @daidai Yeah I can't connect to built-in VPN either, after the newtest update. Can you recommend me an client?

Comment: Before using VPN client, you could try to check the Registry in the link below https://superuser.com/questions/1020970/cant-connect-to-l2tp-ipsec-vpn-on-windows-but-works-fine-on-phone-on-same-netwo, For VPN client, OpenVPN is a choice.

Comment: @daidai Hahah, I got an update today for 1703 and seems that I can connect to VPN again